# ASP.NET 5: Upload file through WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core

I'm sending file to WebApi using Jquery.ajax
I have an ASP.NET method that receives file

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("import")]
public int Import([FromBody]IFormFile upload)
```

Inside Import method a can save Request.Body and it looks correct:

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryZLHvtGDqa5zp0JHB Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; filename="test.b3d" 
>   Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>
> Hello world content!

but upload variable is always null! What should I fix to have file contents inside "upload" variable?

PS: I send file to server using this code:

```
    // Create a formdata object and add the files
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("upload", file.files[0]);

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/designer/import",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        data: data
    })
```

The request headers in Chrome:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:28855
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:localhost:64867
Origin:http://localhost:64867
Referer:http://localhost:64867/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: can you share how the request headers look like in chrome?

Comment: Yeah, I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `FromBody` attribute decorated on the parameter to enable binding data of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

This is a change from how existing Web API works. You can use `FromBody` in cases other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, like `application/json`, `application/xml` etc.

Comment: It doesn't help... maybe I have smth wrong in jquery.ajax call? Can you look at it (I've added the code at the bottom of the question)